# Maximum Call stack Exceeded in jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm facing the problem in jQuery autocomplete if I used focus() method inside my jQuery autocomplete then it throws maxim call stack exceeded and sometime I couldn't clear what I'm typed in the input type also. my code looks like

```
onSelect: function (output) {   
  $("#studentID").val(output.data);    
  $('#StudentName').focus(); 
},
```

If I comment the focus() method then there is no errors will happen, I have the validation of this field that validation only removed by focus() method

If I comment the focus() method then there is no errors will happen, I have the validation of this field that validation only removed by focus() method

Maximum call stack error could not be thrown thats my only concern

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - never focus something that may trigger something on focus

```
onSelect: function (output) {   
  $("#studentID").val(output.data);    
  setTimeout(() => $('#StudentName').focus(),10); 
},
```